# Zip::ZipFile: How to modify contents of inner textfiles without unpacking zip?

Tags: ruby, zip

Cheers, 
as a beginner to ruby, I am currently in the process of solving my smaller-world problems with ruby, to get accustomed to it. Right now I am trying to modify the contents of a text file within a zip container.

the Structure is

```
ZIP
  >> diretory/
     >> mytext.text
```

And I am able to iterate over the contents

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(file_path) do |zipfile|
  files = zipfile.select(&:file?)
  files.each do |zip_entry|
    ## ....?
  end
end
```

...but I find it very difficult to modify the text file without unpacking it.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So with the help of Ben, here's one solution:

```
require "rubygems"
require "zip/zip"
zip_file_name = "src/test.zip"

Zip::ZipFile.open(zip_file_name) do |zipfile|
  files = zipfile.select(&:file?)
  files.each do |zip_entry|
    contents = zipfile.read(zip_entry.name)
    zipfile.get_output_stream(zip_entry.name){ |f| f.puts contents + ' added some text' }
  end
  zipfile.commit
end
```

I though I had tried this before - anyways. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's legacy support of `zip/zip` but as of the latest version you should probably start using `require 'rubyzip'`. (https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip)

Answer (score 1):

This snip bit adds " added some text" to the end of myFile.txt.

```
Zip::File.open(file_path) do |zipfile|
  contents = zipfile.read('myFile.txt')
  zipfile.get_output_stream('myFile.txt') { |f| f.puts contents + ' added some text' }
end
```

<strike>For some reason, the modifications to the zip file aren't saved if the writing (the call to get_output_stream) is done while using `each` to iterate over the archive's files.</strike>

*Edit:* To modify files while iterating over them via each, open the archive with Zip::ZipFile.open (see Chris's answer for an example).

Hopefully, this snip bit will help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey, that's nearly "it"... I knew I had to "zipfile.commit" from the http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html

Comment: Interesting...from my experimenting on a Windows system with Ruby 1.9.2, zipfile.commit isn't necessary with either of our answers. Which OS and Ruby version are you running?

Comment: Well i have Not confirmed this is not working without 'commit'. I have been first trying this in Windows 7 and  now got The Solution pm my Mac.